# C# MVC Entity Framework needs CREATE TABLE permission - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple C# MVC website with Entity Framework.
Created a simple model, DBContext, Controller and View.

Everything works great - but as soon as I lock down the SQL User to only query the SQL View that is needed I get the following:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDatabase'.
```

Again, everything works if the user has the CREATE TABLE permission but this shouldn't be necessary.

How to avaid that?

Best regards

Comment: If you're using code first (with migrations?) then I imagine the framework would need additional permissions to update the schema when the model changes.  How exactly are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Are you using `Database.SetInitializer` anywhere?

Comment: Have no idea, have installed the Entity Framework nuget package. Created a very simple model, dbcontextmodel, controller and view. Thats it. I am new to this :) So forgive me

Comment: The default initializer is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` which is why it is trying to create those tables.

Comment: Hey Mrchief, thank you for your answer. The database does exists though. How can I change the default initializer?